# Adding Cordova to iOS project 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

I have a project made using Cordova (platform iOS). I need to integrate it into another iOS project. I have followed the instructions mentioned at this [link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html). I am able to successfully compile the app. However once I run it on device I get the following exception,

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'm new to iOS and Cordova and not sure how to debug this. It seems to occur at the place where I'm trying to use `CDVViewController` instance.

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>

CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
[viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[myView addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Does anyone know why this exception would occur in the current scenario? Here's all the logs:

```
2017-04-27 18:41:23.511589 project_name[2426:796658] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2017-04-27 18:41:23.729848 project_name[2426:796603] Couldn't find the "com.apple.private.externalaccessory.showallaccessories" entitlement
2017-04-27 18:41:23.733971 project_name[2426:796603] SDK Version: 0.5
2017-04-27 18:41:23.787330 project_name[2426:796603] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.3.1 is starting.
2017-04-27 18:41:23.787817 project_name[2426:796603] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2017-04-27 18:41:23.793568 project_name[2426:796603] -[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174057670
2017-04-27 18:41:23.795231 project_name[2426:796603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174057670'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184cae1c0 0x1836e855c 0x184cb5278 0x184cb2278 0x184bac59c 0x100043588 0x18ab020b0 0x18ab01c78 0x10003e480 0x18ab020b0 0x18ab01c78 0x18ab08424 0x18ab766c8 0x10004110c 0x18ab74100 0x18ad84858 0x18ad8a5c8 0x18ad9ee60 0x18ad875ac 0x1868558bc 0x186855728 0x186855ad0 0x184c5c278 0x184c5bbc0 0x184c597c0 0x184b88048 0x18ab6d2b0 0x18ab68034 0x1000414e0 0x183b6c5b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just posting what resolved the issue for me, in case someone needs it in future. Turns out the link I was referring to for steps was cached or something and the previous version did not instruct to add Cordova.framework. Once I added the .framework file to my iOS project, the issue was resolved. It now builds and runs fine.

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  What exact were the steps you took?  Could you take a look at my stack post please

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61293865/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-running